# how to disable the UI until a response from the server with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, express

I am building a web app with [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) and [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) ([express](/questions/tagged/express)).

Many times in my app a user will do things that will comunicate with the server and according to the result things will happen.

Whenever a user calls something that needs a response from the server i would like the UI to be on hold and won't let the user do anything else. Thus preventing the user from clicking buttons many times and overloading my server.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you can, avoid doing this. Whenever possible, allow the user to continue to do things even though you have a call pending.

When you *can't*, you can use a [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), which will overlay the page with a masking element. Then remove the modal when you're done. You can make this fairly unobtrusive by playing with the modal's settings.

Alternately, of course, your application could just have a flag indicating that there's an outstanding request to the server (possibly using jQuery's [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)), and disable further actions when that flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ng-disabled`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled) directive on the button to disable the button after it has been clicked once.

Controller:

```
$scope.isDisabled = false;

$scope.submitForm = function() {
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
    // submit form and wait for response here
    // reset isDisabled when you get it
}
```

HTML:

```
 <button ng-click="submitForm()" disabled="{{scope.isDisabled}}">Submit</button>
```

If you need something more general, Angular's ajax [interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) can allow you to set a variable before a request and when a response is received. You can use this to customise the UI, disallowing what you want stopped based on whether the interceptor has completed.